# SQL Server Transaction log backup failed 665 "The requested operation could not be completed due to file system limitation"

Tags: sql-server

I am taking the transaction log backup in SQL Server 2012 for the database "XXXX".

While taking the transaction log backup (after executing 60%), it throws this error:

> Backup failed for server AAAA (Microsoft.Sqlserver.SmoExtended)
>   Additional Information:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError:
>   Write on "" failed 665: (The requested operation could not be completed dut to file system limitation)

Please assist.

Comment: Have you checked all Google suggestions first and found that they don't help you? Hint: Google "sql server The requested operation could not be completed dut to file system limitation"

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you:

1. Run a Windows defragment on the volume where the spooling
   folder is located.
2. Alternatively, pick a different, less fragmented volume to spool the
   database to.

> When a sparse file (used for snapshot database files) is populated Windows limits the amount of data that may reside in the file. Once the amount of data stored in the sparse file exceeds the limit further data storage in the file may be prevented.

Also:

- Run `DBCC CHECKDB` in `OFFLINE` mode (`WITH TABLOCK`)
- Run `DBCC CHECKDB` at a time when less data modification is taking
  place
- Divide the database into a few more files. The limitations are per
  sparse file and each database snapshot creates matching sparse files
  for each database file. For example if the database files are each
  limited to `64GB` in total size you can't exceed the limitation on a
  per file basis.
- Remove snapshot databases that have grown large.

[Reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2008/07/10/sql-server-reports-operating-system-error-1450-or-1452-or-665-retries/)

I hope be helpful for you :)

Comment: The OP does not use sparse NTFS files, the recommendations above are for someone who experience this error while doing dbcc checkdb because it creates a snapshot of db (and it does not create it when using with tablock)